# Помощь по mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite, php, .htaccess

Архитектура срипта предусматривает одну точку входа — `index.php`. `Через $_GET['c']` идет обработка контроллеров: `index.php?c=login` — страница логина и т.д.

Нынешний .htaccess делает следующее: `RewriteRule .* index.php?c=$0`, то есть `site.ua/login`. Но я хочу, чтоб была возможность ловить из массива GET. Например, при постраничной навигации: `site.ua/films/?p=2`. То есть сейчас всё, что после «?», идет в массив такого себе хренороутинга, но мне нужно, как описано выше.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переписать правила.

Answer (score 1):

Пропиши перед этим RewriteRule свой RewiteRule для раздела films, чтобы не происходило никакого Rewrite в случае, если адрес начинается с films.

**Обновление**

[[@Dima Logginoff](/users/17409/dima-logginoff)](/users/17409/dima-logginoff), ты сам хоть что-нибудь сделал? Хешкод - это не бесплатная биржа свободных от работы фрилансеров. Я не вижу у тебя в профиле ни одного ответа. Т.е. твоя помощь другим участникам сообщества равна 0. Получается, что ты только паразитируешь на нем. Или тебе пока рано пользоваться такими сайтами. Почитай самостоятельно про URL-преобразования здесь http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/mod_rewrite/index.php

Что будет не понятно - спрашивай.

Comment: Подскажите пример, пожалуйста

Comment: Да без вопросов, сам решу проблему. Спасибо.